# 20.04: Blank Screen after timeout not working anymore

Tags: screen

when setting the Blank Screen timeout in *Settings/Power/Power Saving* the screen doesn't blank after the set timeout elapses while being idle.
It has worked earlier but about two weeks ago it stopped working.

How can this be made working again?

Thanks!

gkerschb

Comment: Have you installed any applications recently that might prevent the system from sleeping? There are a number of tools that will do this for people watching videos or otherwise *looking* at their computers a long time without actually interacting.

Comment: I'm not aware of any apps that prevent sleeping. Now the problem is gone. I think a reboot solved the problem in some way. Thanks!